# What does the prefix ご in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

I'm aware that

```
ご家族は何人ですか
```

means how many people are in your family?
But the ご how is used? What does mean?

It would be the same as

```
あなたの家族は何人ですか/家族は何人ですか?
```

Comment: Would these threads be of some help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49073/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2111/9831

Comment: It’s a prefix, not a particle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to the honorific お.

[Japanese honorific prefixes お and ご (‘O’ and ‘Go’)](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/03/21/japanese-honorific-prefixes-%E3%81%8A-and-%E3%81%94-o-and-go/)

Answer (score -1):

ご is used as a respected word.
for example, if you are a questioner for a boss, you should use ご.

Comment: then its the same than  おなまえは?